# Is the limit of a square root equal to the square root of the limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

First I will assume that $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, being $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = \infty$. Then, can I say that $$\lim_{x \to c} \sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} = \sqrt{\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} \, ?$$

Applying the power rule, I think I can, but I want to be sure. Is the existence of $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ a sufficient condition for the rule to be correct?

Comment: This is true due to continuity of $\sqrt{}$, you can convince yourself in this way: if $x$ is close enough to $c$, then by condition on $f,g$ $f(x)/g(x)$ is very close to the limit, so by continuity of square root the whole thing is close to $\sqrt{\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$. You can of course turn this into a rigourous proof, but I think spotting this is enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square root is a continuous function.

Hence, we can bring in the limit inside the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what continuous function is:

$f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)\left(=f\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a}x\right)\right)$

Now let's assume that square root is continuous, if you want the proof for this read about epsilon-delta.

If square root is continuous then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\sqrt{y(x)}=\sqrt{\lim\limits_{x\to a}y(x)}$

In your case $y(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$